# how to avoid fake users to register my Joomla site

Tags: security, joomla, registration, joomla3.0

I have a Joomla site that allows users registration. Form registration uses captcha plugin that comes with Joomla.

The problem is that I am constantly receiving fake registrations. Most of them, users do not validate account, but a few do.

All fake accounts that are created share the same caracteristics. First, the user name is strange (for example, karenpv3, Richardmacy, HanReal47p, xzusaymeznxxzcf, and so on), the e-mail is clearly, in most cases, invented, the country is generally from east Europe (Russia, Poland, Ukraine, Romania, Germany, Etc.) and the phone number is a number always with the same number of digits.

With the country information, I have used this site https://www.ip2location.com/blockvisitorsbycountry.aspx to block users using Linux firewall (Iptables). On the other hand, I have installed a plugin that sends me an e-mail each time a user registers the site and tells me about the IP address. With that information, I realized that not all network masks are considered in the IpTables. For example, a user came from IP 213.80.232.35 (Russia), however, the site above added iptable entry 213.80.128.0/17 so I have to add manually 213.80.0.0/16 in order to block that whole network.

Since my form has Recaptcha feature, I think it is not a bot who registers but a real human or spammers have found a way to hack recaptcha.

Is there a more effective way to avoid those fake registrations? what spammers or hackers can get with this?

This is Joomla 3.6.5

Regards
Jaime

Answer (score 1):

This is a very challenging task but as a Joomla programmer myself I was able to tackle with spam registration using some very useful tools from Joomla.

1) [DomainRestriction](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/access-a-security/site-access/domainrestriction/)
This plugin allows or deny registration to specific email, domain and perform automatic group assignments on IP (address or CIDR network), email, domain or TLD.

I only allowed mail registrations from gmail.com, yahoo.com, mail.com.

You also have this [User Mail Restriction](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/user-mail-restriction/), but I have not tested it.

2)You can also use this [Spamhaus SBL/XBL Blacklist Site Protection](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/spamhaus-sbl-xbl-blacklist-site-protection/) 
This will query the Spamhaus SBL/XBL database to see if your visitor's IP is listed. If they are, then it will block them with a message.

3) Stop Bot registration using [Stop Registration Bots](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/stop-registration-bots/)

Also you cannot avoid it completely but you can definitely reduce it.

Regarding the purpose:

- They register in your site to access the registered contents.
- To spread spam in your form.
- To get some backlinks for their sites.
- Sometimes even to upload malicious files.

At the end I recommend you to have a regular scan of your website using [Centrora Security](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/access-a-security/site-security/centrora-security/)

This will keep your website safe from hackers.

Answer (score 1):

If is a real human it will be hard to do something.
But for spam and bots please try a plug in: **ECC+ - EasyCalcCheck Plus** by Developer: Viktor Vogel
For me is currently the best what i find for my Joomla sites. Is free is light and very effective.
 Hope that help good luck.

Answer (score 0):

1. If they're defeating CAPTCHA, an alternative is [Proof of Work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof-of-work_system). Make the browser spend a few seconds calculating the prime factors of a very large number
2. You could add phone verification. User enters phone number. Use a service like Twilio to call them and read a random number. User enters number on your site to confirm registration